# The Gray area of n-ary codes

Tags: code-golf, conversion, coding-theory

Write a program or function that takes a base `n` and a number `x`, and returns or outputs the [`n`-ary Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#n-ary_Gray_code) of `x`.

### Rules

- `n` is an integer in the range `2 <= n <= 16`.
- `x` is an integer in the range `0 <= n < 2**32`.
- The inputted numbers can either be two integer arguments if you write a function, or two arguments to `ARGV` or a space separated pair to `STDIN` if you write a program.
- The output should be a string, either returned or printed to `STDOUT`.
- If `n` is 10 or more, use hex digits to represent digits with a value greater than 9. The case of the digits does not matter.
- If the `n`-ary Gray code of `x` is zero, `'0'` must be printed or returned.
- Code length is in bytes, and standard loopholes are not permitted.
- You do not need to use the same algorithm as below, but if you use a different one, make sure it produces valid Gray codes.

### Example

Example code adapted from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#n-ary_Gray_code):

```
>>> import string
>>> 
>>> def nary_gray_code(base, num):
...     base_num = []
...     # Convert to num to base base
...     while num:
...         base_num.append(num % base)
...         num = num // base
...     # Convert base base number to base-ary Gray code
...     shift = 0
...     gray = []
...     for b in reversed(base_num):
...         gray.insert(0, (b + shift) % base)
...         shift += base - gray[0]
...     return "".join(string.hexdigits[i] for i in reversed(gray)) or "0"
... 
>>> nary_gray_code(2, 100)
'1010110'
>>> nary_gray_code(2, 1)
'1'
>>> nary_gray_code(2, 0)
'0'
>>> nary_gray_code(10, 23)
'21'
>>> nary_gray_code(10, 100)
'190'
>>> nary_gray_code(3, 26)
'200'
>>> nary_gray_code(3, 27)
'1200'
>>> for i in range(2, 17):
...     print(i, nary_gray_code(i, 2**32 - 1))
... 
2 10000000000000000000000000000000
3 122102120011102000122
4 3000000000000000
5 34020102231331
6 1401154214013
7 260241350125
8 34000000000
9 11762782617
10 4875571576
11 1824007509
12 92b627446
13 5b25a2c00
14 2ac96ab2b
15 197dde1a7
16 f0000000
>>>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that there are many different gray codes, so you can't test through equality with some test set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Pyth, 20 bytes

```
Msme.H%dGu+G-HsGjHGY
```

This defines a function `g` which takes two integers as parameters. Take a look at this online demonstration: [Pyth Compiler/Executor](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Msme.H%25dGu%2BG-HsGjHGY%0Ag+2+100%0Ag+2+1%0Ag+2+0%0Ag+10+23%0Ag+10+100%0Ag+3+26%0Ag+3+27%0Ag+2+4294967295%0Ag+3+4294967295%0Ag+4+4294967295%0Ag+5+4294967295%0Ag+6+4294967295%0Ag+7+4294967295%0Ag+8+4294967295%0Ag+9+4294967295%0Ag+10+4294967295%0Ag+11+4294967295%0Ag+12+4294967295%0Ag+13+4294967295%0Ag+14+4294967295%0Ag+15+4294967295%0Ag+16+4294967295&debug=0).

### Explanation:

```
Msme.H%dGu+G-HsGjHGY  
M                     def g(G, H): return _
                jHG      convert H to base G
         u      jHGY     reduce(lambda G, H: _, jHG, [])
          +G-HsG            G + [H - sum(G)]
  m                      map each number d to:
   e.H%dG                   hex-representation(d % G)[-1]
 s                       sum (join all digits)
```

This code is a little bit confusing. There are 4 function parameters in this code: two of them are called `G` and two of them are called `H`. The `G` in `+G-HsG` is different from the `G` in `jHG` or `%dG`.

Comment: I don't think the problem description allows newline as a separator.

Comment: @isaacg Your right. Changed it into a function, still 20 bytes.